# Serializing a h2o model with pickle - python

Tags: python, serialization, machine-learning, h2o

I am currently trying to serialize a h2o gb model into a pickle object and reuse it. Due to some constraints, I can't use the default method or POJO and MOJO given at - http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/productionizing.html. The model gets pickled, however on unpickling(pickle.loads), the following error comes up -

```
__new__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'keyvals'
```

The code below for reference-

```
import h2o as h2o
import pickle as pickle
from h2o.estimators.gbm import H2OGradientBoostingEstimator
h2o.init()

csv_url = "https://h2o-public-test-data.s3.amazonaws.com/smalldata/wisc/wisc-diag-breast-cancer-shuffled.csv"
data = h2o.import_file(csv_url)
y = 'diagnosis'
x = data.columns
del x[0:1]
train, test = data.split_frame(ratios=[0.75], seed=1)


model = H2OGradientBoostingEstimator(distribution='bernoulli',
                                ntrees=100,
                                max_depth=4,
                                learn_rate=0.1)
model.train(x=x, y=y, training_frame=train, validation_frame=test)

loaded_model = pickle.loads(saved_model)
perf = loaded_model.model_performance(test)
perf.auc()
```

I tried to understand the pickle module and make some changes, but it didn't work. Any workaround/help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I am also looking for a way to pickel an h2o model. have you found how to do it?  we need some save/load standard across different ml packages

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pickle it, h2o provides its own persistence methods: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/save-and-load-model.html

```
# build the model
model = H2ODeepLearningEstimator(params)
model.train(params)

# save the model
model_path = h2o.save_model(model=model, path="/tmp/mymodel", force=True)

print(model_path)
# outputs: /tmp/mymodel/DeepLearning_model_python_1441838096933

# load the model
saved_model = h2o.load_model(model_path)
```

be warned though, persisted models are ***NOT*** compatible between even the most minor version changes i.e. if you train and save a model in 3.18.0.1 you won't be able to load it in 3.18.0.2

Comment: That approach was working for me before. Thanks though. Looking to solve it through pickle if it's possible.